# Run post-build process after build completely finishes

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, build-automation, madexcept

I'm using Delphi XE2 and madExcept.  I want to run a process after the build finishes, including the madExcept stuff that occurs at the end of the build process.

Putting my batch-file in the `post-build events` causes my batch-file to run before the madExcept stuff finishes.  I thought perhaps I could spawn a detached process using the DOS `start` command that would pause for a few seconds so the build can finish, then the paused process can do its tasks.  I tried the following as the post-build command:

```
start "" cmd /c "timeout /t 5&RunPostBuild.bat"
```

However, instead of opening a separate window and continuing the build process, Delphi opens a window, waits the 5 seconds, runs `RunPostBuild.bat` and then finishes the build process. The result is the same; `RunPostBuild.bat` still runs *before* madExcept does its stuff.

Does anyone know how to truly run a process automatically at the **end** of the build process, including the madExcept stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can disable the post-processing that madExcept does in the IDE, you could then add that as part of the post-build operations by running madExceptPatch.exe. [The madExcept FAQ](http://help.madshi.net/madExceptFaq.htm) suggests using the -gd flag.

Comment: This is precisely how I deal with the issue. In fact I don't have the madExcept packages installed at all and just do a plain madexceptpatch in my post build.

Comment: I like this solution much better.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it from the IDE alone.  However, if you create a scheduled task to run once, delete the trigger (so just the task remains with no schedule of when to run), then you can add a command to the `post-build events` to run the task on-demand.  Delphi will immediately return and finish the build process even though the task hasn't completed yet.

By putting a `timeout /t 5` at the start of the batch file that the scheduled task runs, 5 seconds will elapse while the IDE finishes the build, then the remaining commands in the batch file will execute.

The command to add to the `post-build events` is:

```
schtasks /run /tn "Name of scheduled task"
```

It works very reliably.